# Getting author names to appear on the same page as front page

Tags: titles, author

I have a small docuemnt in latex which has a front page that I am quite happy with. My current overleaf doc looks like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}




\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}   

\fancyhead[R]{
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/itu.jpeg}
}

\author{Thomas  Johnson\\
   \texttt{thta@itu.dk}
\and Tom gurtso\\
    \texttt{guts@itu.dk}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{0.5cm}
        

        \Huge
        \textbf{Is LoRaRatchet even that nice?}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        I dunno
       \vspace*{0.5cm}
       
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/suchHaz.jpeg}
        \maketitle
            \setlength{\droptitle}{50em}   


        
\newsavebox{\logo}
\savebox{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.75in]{figures/itu.jpeg}}
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\date{October 2021}


\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The issue is right now about the `author` tag, which contains the names and emails of two authors, that I would like to have displayed in on my frontpage.
The issue is that the authors are currently pushed a page down, and stands on the page following the front page:

[image]

Where I would like it directly below the image.
It does'nt really make sense to me, since I use `\maketitle` to add the author names, which is contained inside the `\begin{titlepage}` block.

How do I make the author names a part of my front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited your MWE because you did not provide your graphics files and you ignored the error messages (which would have given you a hint about what your problem was).

```
% titlepageprob.tex  SE 623434

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in, headheight=35.4pt, footskip=35.4pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{mwe} % to get example images
\usepackage{comment}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}   

\setlength{\headheight}{90pt} % latex complained headheight too small

\fancyhead[R]{
%\includegraphics[width=4cm]{figures/itu.jpeg}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
}

\begin{comment}  % only useful for \maketitle
\author{Thomas  Johnson\\
   \texttt{thta@itu.dk}
\and Tom gurtso\\
    \texttt{guts@itu.dk}
}
\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{0.5cm}
        

        \Huge
        \textbf{Is LoRaRatchet even that nice?}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        I dunno
       \vspace*{0.5cm}
       
%        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{figures/suchHaz.jpeg}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-a}
%        \maketitle  % you have not defined a \title
            \setlength{\droptitle}{50em}   

\begin{center}
Thomas  Johnson\\
   \texttt{thta@itu.dk} \\
and \\
Tom gurtso\\
    \texttt{guts@itu.dk} \\

\end{center}

\begin{center}
October 21,  2021 \par
\end{center}        
\newsavebox{\logo}
%\savebox{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.75in]{figures/itu.jpeg}}
\savebox{\logo}{\includegraphics[width=0.75in]{example-image-b}}
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

%\date{October 2021} % used by \maketitle


\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

The typeset result does not look good but everything is on the one page. I didn't waste my time trying to make it look good (your `\Huge` applies throughout the `titlepage`).

[image]

You are entirely responsible for what appears on a `titlepage`. You have tried to mix an error producing `\maketitle` with `titlingpage`. I suggest you do one or the other but not both.